# bean evaluation in camel

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, apache-camel

I want to fetch one value from my camel body. which has construction like this

```
 <header>

        <rules>
            <datas>
                <data>
                    <name>route</name>
                    <elements>
                        <element>
                            <name>serve</name>
                            <value>V001</value>
                            <type>String</type>
                        </element>
                        <element>
                            <name>operation</name>
                            <value>update</value>
                            <type>String</type>
                        </element>
                    </element>
                </data>
            </datas>
        </rules>
    </header>
```

I want to fetch value of  "value"  tag of 1st "element"
for this  I have written expression like this

```
${body.header.rules.datas.data[0].elements[0].element.value}
```

here my "elements" and "datas" are of list type
but it failed to evaluate this expression and throwing null pointer. please can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the type of the body of the exchange at the time you run the expression? is it a  Java POJO or an xml Document?

Comment: Java POJO when I am trying to evaluate this expression

Comment: My suggestion is to use a processor and while debugging use the SimpleBuilder to  evaluate the expression incrementally to find the error.Here I am evaluationg until rules->SimpleBuilder.simple("${body.header.rules}").evaluate(exchange, String.class);

Comment: I guess that you probably want `.elements.element[0]` instead of `.elements[0].element` (judging from the XML, I expect `element` to be a list in Java, because it's a repeating element in XML) - but if your question is about manipulating a POJO, you really should post your Java model, not your XML model, in your question!

Comment: hey thanks..it didn't help me directly but it helped me to figure out my problem..:)

Comment: @LowCool you should post the answer and accept it so others with similar issues can get help.